# Cannot create proper URL for Geocoding API

Tags: geocoding

Using Pentaho to send addresses to Mapquest for long/lat info.

**This is the URL I am sending:**

```
www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=MYKEY&inFormat=json&json={location: lookup_address}, options:{thumbMaps:false,maxResults:1}
```

The "lookup_address" field is the concatenated address for the API.

It keeps returning Invalid query.
Unable to get result from specified URL :

```
http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=MYKEY&json={location: {lookup_address}, options:{thumbMaps:false,maxResults:1}}&address=%70%20SouthBay%20Ave.%22%22Boston%22%22MA%22%2202118%22
```

If I put this into the URL it is fine.

```
www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=APPKEY&inFormat=json&json={location:%2270%20South%20Bay%20Ave.%20Boston,%20MA%2002118%22}
```

What is the proper syntax to send the string properly?

Comment: mapquest is having some technical issues current as they release a new service yesterday (11th July 2017) https://devblog.mapquest.com/2017/07/11/announcement-mapquest-js-public-release/

Comment: The correct format is https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/geocoding-api/address/get/ example http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=KEY&location=Washington,DC (you have spaces in your second example)